# I'm trying to scrape a web page and find_element() can't find the element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape a list of links for AIESEC opportunities.
Here's a link, for example, https://aiesec.org/opportunity/global-volunteer/1291411
this opportunity provides : Accommodation, Transportation and food
I want to make selenium scrape all info then append this info in a spreadsheet
here's the code I use :

```
import time
import gspread
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = r'C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\AIESECSCRAPER\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)
opp_links = wks.col_values(4)
MC_row = 1
project_row = 1
slots_row = 1
acc_pro = 1
acc_cov = 1
tra_pro = 1
tra_cov = 1
food_pro = 1
food_cov = 1
food_no = 1

for url in opp_links:
    #try:
        Transportation = ''
        Food = ''
        browser.get(url)
        time.sleep(20)
        MC_name = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"info-main\"]/section/div[1]/div/span[3]").get_attribute(
            'innerHTML')
        project_name = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"info-main\"]/section/div[1]/p[2]").get_attribute(
            'innerHTML')
        Accommodation = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                             "//*[@id=\"logistics\"]/app-logistics/div/div[1]/div[1]/p[2]").get_attribute(
            'innerHTML')
        try:
            Transportation = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                  "//*[@id=\"logistics\"]/app-logistics/div/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]").get_attribute(
                'innerHTML')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            wks.update_acell(f'J{tra_pro}', 'not_provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'K{tra_cov}', 'not_covered')

        try:
            Food = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                        "//*[@id=\"logistics\"]/app-logistics/div/div[1]/div[3]/p[2]").get_attribute(
                'innerHTML')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            wks.update_acell(f'L{food_pro}', 'not_provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'M{food_cov}', 'not_covered')
            wks.update_acell(f'N{food_no}', '0')

        slots = []
        try:
            for label in range(1, 30):
                date = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                        f"//*[@id=\"slots\"]/app-slots/div/label[{label}]/div/p").get_attribute(
                'innerHTML')
                slots.append(date)
        except:
            pass
        print(MC_name)
        print(project_name)
        print(slots)
        print(Accommodation)
        print(Transportation)
        print(Food)

        wks.update_acell(f'A{MC_row}', MC_name)
        wks.update_acell(f'C{slots_row}', str(slots))
        wks.update_acell(f'F{project_row}', project_name)

        if Accommodation == 'A place to stay will be provided and paid for.':
            wks.update_acell(f'H{acc_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'I{acc_cov}', 'covered')
        elif Accommodation == 'A place to stay will be provided but not paid for. You will have to cover the cost.':
            wks.update_acell(f'H{acc_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'I{acc_cov}', 'not_covered')
        elif Transportation == "A means of transportation will be provided and paid for.":
            wks.update_acell(f'J{tra_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'K{tra_cov}', 'covered')
        elif Transportation == 'A means of transportation will be provided but not paid for. You will have to cover the cost.':
            wks.update_acell(f'J{tra_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'K{tra_cov}', 'not_covered')
        elif Food == '1  meals  per day will be provided and paid for.':
            wks.update_acell(f'L{food_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'M{food_cov}', 'covered')
            wks.update_acell(f'N{food_no}', '1')
        elif Food == '2  meals  per day will be provided and paid for.':
            wks.update_acell(f'L{food_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'M{food_cov}', 'covered')
            wks.update_acell(f'N{food_no}', '2')
        elif Food == '3  meals  per day will be provided and paid for.':
            wks.update_acell(f'L{food_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'M{food_cov}', 'covered')
            wks.update_acell(f'N{food_no}', '3')
        elif Food == '1  meals  per day will be provided but not paid for. You will have to cover the cost.':
            wks.update_acell(f'L{food_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'M{food_cov}', 'not_covered')
            wks.update_acell(f'N{food_no}', '1')
        elif Food == '2  meals  per day will be provided but not paid for. You will have to cover the cost.':
            wks.update_acell(f'L{food_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'M{food_cov}', 'not_covered')
            wks.update_acell(f'N{food_no}', '2')
        elif Food == '3  meals  per day will be provided but not paid for. You will have to cover the cost.':
            wks.update_acell(f'L{food_pro}', 'provided')
            wks.update_acell(f'M{food_cov}', 'not_covered')
            wks.update_acell(f'N{food_no}', '3')

        MC_row = MC_row + 1
        project_row = project_row + 1
        slots_row = slots_row + 1
        acc_pro = acc_pro + 1
        acc_cov = acc_cov + 1
        tra_pro = tra_pro + 1
        tra_cov = tra_cov + 1
        food_pro = food_pro + 1
        food_cov = food_cov + 1
    #except:
        #print('error in this URL: ' + url)
        #MC_row = MC_row + 1
        #project_row = project_row + 1
        #slots_row = slots_row + 1
        #acc_pro = acc_pro + 1
        #acc_cov = acc_cov + 1
        #tra_pro = tra_pro + 1
        #tra_cov = tra_cov + 1
        #food_pro = food_pro + 1
        #food_cov = food_cov + 1
        #pass
browser.quit()
```

it returns

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/app-root/div[1]/app-opportunity-v2/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/section[5]/app-logistics/div/div[1]/div[3]/p[2]"}
```

I tried to use CSS selector instead of XPATH but it gives same result

Comment: I don't see where you are fetching that URL here.

Comment: I have the spreadsheet already but I removed these lines from the code

Answer (score 0):

Doing a scraping on

> https://aiesec.org/opportunity/global-volunteer/1291411

Is not failing, so the issue should be on the pages you are trying to scrape.

Check manually on the URLs of  `wks.col_values(4)`

Comment: It fails, I manually checked all URLs I have and they're working

Comment: Run the program and it won't find the element and won't update cells